# Summing the sequence of a data function matrix

Tags: real-analysis

I have to convolute two linear binomial and need to Sum it over a particular input domain, given that the matrix is two linear binomials, is that possible? 
A straight linear sequence is well known and it's summing operation, but how do we sum matrix values of the convolution of two linear binomials since its location depends upon two variables, not one as in a monomial  linear equation?
Any suggestions?